# Allow community to select an answer for an abandoned question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Lately on money I have been noticing a large number of questions where the OP abandoned the question or did not bother selecting/like the answers provided.

As this is not a personal advice site, I guess the community in general can decide if one of the answers provided meet the selection criteria and mark it accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community can **vote answers up or down**, but there is no mechanism for accepting an answer on the OP's behalf.  Only the OP has this capability.

Yet, there's also no *requirement* that there be an accepted answer to the question.  A question can remain without an "accepted" answer indefinitely.

Personally, I consider the "accept answer" action strictly as a way for the asker to award extra reputation to an answer they found most helpful.  It need not be the "best" or "most-correct" answer.

Comment: Let's say there is a question with a lot of answers. People who have the same question can read all of them and still be unsure of what the answer should be. The community in general has an implicit understanding of what it should have been and can guide those people. I guess votes to an answer is a solution, but it does not have the same level of "closure" as an accepted answer does.

Comment: In the case you describe, that question is begging for a better answer to be written.   If there are 6 answers, all with 0 or 1 votes, there is an opportunity to write a better answer and it will get more votes than all previous answers.

Comment: I appreciate the clarifications

Answer (score 1):

As [Chris W. Rea explained](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/487/1061), there's no requirement for an answer to be accepted on every question.

An accepted answer often just means the asker found the answer most helpful, but it's not always an indication of the best, most comprehensive, or the most correct answer. The only person who can pick the answer that was most helpful to the asker is the asker themselves, but the community can pick the answer it likes best through upvoting it.

There are no plans to introduce a "community acceptance" feature at this time.

Comment: I appreciate the clarifications